# jqGrid return rowData as string

Tags: jquery-plugins, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I have local data for jqGrid and I make custom formatter for boolean column. Something like

```
var boolFormatter = function (cellvalue, opt, rowObj) {
  if (cellvalue == null) return "";
  return (cellvalue == true)
    ? return "Yes"
    : return "No";
}
```

My colmodel like

```
var colmodel = [
 {index: id, name: id, hidden: true}
 {index: someProperty, name: someProperty, formatter: boolFormatter}
]
```

the problem is when I call rowData for the object, I get string value, i.e.

```
var rowData = grid.getRowData(1);
var value = rowData["someProperty"];
```

**<= this will return "Yes", "No" or "" instead of true, false or null.**

I know that this is content values, and jqGrid has it's internal data storage, where I believe all data are stored in normal (true, false, values) formats.

Please, help, how can I get them as bool. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In function `boolFormatter` you return value `""` when `cellvalue == null` and return value `return "Yes"
    : return "No"` when `cellvalue == true`. That is why you got `string` values.

Update your code with below one

```
var boolFormatter = function (cellvalue, opt, rowObj) {
    if (cellvalue == null) {
       return null;
    } else {
       return (cellvalue == true) ? return true : return false;
    }
}
```